# Reputation Job Crisis. How to proceed?

Tags: career-development, careers

I am at a crisis now. I feel I have been blacklisted from many companies because of my actions. I have job hopped from 15 companies with no notice. I am 35 years old. I have crippling Anxiety and am working on this now with a therapist. This all started with my second job where I was backdoored and fired because employees didn't like me.

It got worse after that when my manager was not going to hire me at first, promised my employee before I joined that they would get my job, but they hired my instead. This was not disclosed to me before and my employee retaliated against me and ruined my reputation in the company. My manager would not fire them, because they were their favorite. I threatened to leave and he got written up and quit. The previous person before me who quit, lost their job, and my manager then was going to replace me with them. I threatened to quit and they wrote a schathing remark about me on Linkden. I didn't see it, but overheard coworkers talking about it. I ended up leaving because of all the emotional abuse.

Fast forward to now, the company I was at, the economy took a turn and i was laid off from my current job due to the economy.

I am applying for jobs, but not getting interviews. I have cleaned my resume up to only include the longer duration jobs, but I think that is not enough. I really don't know what to do. Has anyone been in this position?

Edit: I understand everyone. I take accountability. I didn't know I had a disability until a few months ago. I am on medication now. I am trying to figure out how to repair the damage

Comment: 'Has anyone been in this position " is not an actionable question and is likely to be closed as off topic. "How might I be able to repair the damage, or work around it" would be more likely to be accepted. Though I don't think there are any magic bullets here; accepting low pay and unattractive jobs and working your ass off are probably necessary, and changing careers completely may be called for.

Comment: "I have job hopped from 15 companies with no notice." You really, **really** need to explain this. As a hiring manager, I can take one or maybe two instances of this but 15 times you couldn't survive another month?

Comment: I understand everyone. I didn't know I had a disability until a few months ago. I am on medication now. I am trying to figure out how to repair the damage.

Comment: Did you burn bridges everywhere or did you leave some of those companies on relatively good terms? Might be worth trying to reach to some of them, explain the situation, accept responsibility and see if they are willing to give you a second chance. If you are flexible and willing to accept lower compensation, temp to hire, or similar arrangements, you might be able to land a job.

Comment: "It got worse after that when my manager was not going to hire me at first, promised my employee before I joined that they would get my job, but they hired my instead." - I am confused by this statement

Comment: @Donald The person working there was promised my job when I was interviewing for it. My manager favored them, but they didn't get my job because the entire interview panel picked me. The person resented me and bad-mouthed me to the entire company as retaliation. I have very bad PTSD from this.

Comment: The entire panel picked you? Sounds like landing work is easy for you.

Answer (score 6):

First things first. The vast majority of companies, regardless of your industry, do not participate in blacklists, promises not to hire people (who then they hire anyway) or writing scathing remarks on LinkedIn. What you've been part of is not typical or normal.

Perhaps you can find the normal segment of your industry in your location. Perhaps you need to seek out a different location, where the hiring decisions are made by people who don't know the people who have hired you and mistreated you, and don't know that you have a habit of quitting without notice.

I recommend leaving LinkedIn and other platforms that are full of people who know you. Your best bet at the moment is that your cleaned up resume tells hiring managers they have a chance at a solid skilled employee who can be counted on. This isn't a turnaround that you can clarify with a cover letter. Become an unknown, like 99% of the people in your industry, and you have a chance. But don't waste it!

Answer (score 1):

It all sounds very dysfunctional.

At the end of the day, if the "economy has taken a turn" in your sector and you've been laid off, then it's probably not surprising that there won't be many positions on offer, and there will probably be many candidates for those positions that are on offer.

Therefore, you might join the reserve army of labour indefinitely until there is an economic uptick, or until political policy reorients towards promoting full employment.

You've already done the obvious things, like clean up your CV. And others have suggested obvious things, like leaving LinkedIn and other social networking sites.

The only other possibilities might be to cast the net across a wider geographic area, or move into another sector if you have transferrable skills.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't know I had a disability until a few months ago. I am on
> medication now. I am trying to figure out how to repair the damage

Assuming you now have your disability under control, you need to be clear about that during interviews.

Acknowledge what you have done. Explain why you did it. Discuss why it won't happen again.